# Entity Framework Database.SqlQuery method calling PostgreSQL function returns DateTime instead of DateTimeOffset

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework-6

do you know how can I get DateTimeOffset when calling PostgreSQL function from Entity Framework using method EFContext.Database.SqlQuery?

I created PostgreSQL functions which returns table with 6 columns, 2 of them have **timestamp with time zone** type.
When I call this function directly from pgAdmin I can see following result for ActionDate column: *'2017-10-10 08:02:33.602553+02'*

But when I use DateTimeOffset in the C# class I get error calling following method: `EFContext.Database.SqlQuery<EligibleClientResponse>("select * from dbo.\"GetEligibleClients\"(:productCoreId, :adviserId, :productCoreCode)"`

**Error:** *"The specified cast from a materialized 'System.DateTime' type to a nullable 'System.DateTimeOffset' type is not valid."*

My C# class is:

```
    public class EligibleClientResponse
{
    public string DashboardSectionCode { get; set; }
    public Guid ClientId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset? BirthDate { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public int ClientStatus { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset? ActionDate { get; set; }
    public string[] Actions { get; set; }
}
```

Richard